# Configure Serilog in separate class library instead of API project

Tags: asp.net-core, serilog

I created a .Net standard library and I moved the entire Serilog configuration to that library.
Now I just referenced class library in API project without adding Serilog packages to API.

Problem: ILogger inside the controller is not logging a message but the message in Program.cs works fine. I understand why it is working in the Program.cs because I am using Serlog's Log.Logger.information() to write a message but the controller is not logging means the dependency injection for ILogger is somewhere broken.

Note: if I eliminate the class library and write the same initialization code in the program.cs and add all Serilog packages in the API project then everything works fine.

I created a sample project and published in Github. API projects can be started and should see a message in console output.
https://github.com/giridharprakash/QuicLog

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Giridhar! It would help to see the structure of your logger initialization code. Are you calling your logger initialization routine at the beginning of `Main()`? Does your routine include the necessary `UseSerilog()` call on `IHostBuilder`?

Comment: Sorry, just saw your sample link, will have a look

Comment: Looks like the source for `UseQuicLog()` is missing from the repo?

Comment: Sorry, it's my bad I pushed all changes to Repo.

Comment: @NicholasBlumhardt - is there any chance you could help with my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71230390/serilog-logging-from-class-library-method-called-from-net-6-minimal-api